# Get value of an element in Handlebars and Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using Handlebars.Js and Ember to make a small app. First Handlebars generate the template

```
{{#each model}}
    <div class="media">
        {{#if isVoted}}
            <a id="voteb" class="pull-left" href="#" {{action 'voteup'}}>
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
              <span id="votec">{{votecount}}</span>
             </a>
         {{else}}
               <a id="voteb" class="pull-left" href="#" {{action 'votedown'}}>
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>
               <span id="votec">{{votecount}}</span>
                </a>  
         {{/if}}
         <div class="media-body col-md-offset-1">
              <h4 class="media-heading"><a id="linkt">{{title}}</a></h4>
          </div>
      </div>
 {{/each}}
```

So there are vote up down buttons, here when a button is clicked action is triggered in Ember

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

actions: {
    voteup: function(){
        this.set('isVoted' , true);
},
    votedown: function(){
        this.set('isVoted' , false);
}
}

});
```

This will change the voted or not state of the button.

However it doesn't change the vote/not voted state of the button. I don't get any errors in the console. So what's the problem here?

And also please tell me a way to detect which vote button is clicked As there will be many?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{#each}}` loops through an array, so should be an `ArrayController` eg.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
})
```

Whereas each media item needs to have it's own properties, so should be using an `ObjectController` eg

```
App.MediaController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isVoted: false,

  actions: {
    voteup: function(){
      this.set('isVoted' , true);
    },
    votedown: function(){
      this.set('isVoted' , false);
    }
  }
});
```

You can achieve this in various different ways, one would be to encapsulate it in a `component`, but in this case the most simple could be to tell the `ArrayController` to use the `ObjectController` you have defined as the `itemController` eg

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'media'
})
```

Here is a working JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/sufudo/2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define the isVoted-var in the controller.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  //or get the initial value from somewhere
  voteUp: false,

  actions: {
    voteup: function(){
      this.set('isVoted' , true);
    },
    votedown: function(){
      this.set('isVoted' , false);
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Well the thing is different buttons have different vote states, let's say if you have voted an item before next time when you load it it will be marked as voted but there are other items that you've not voted as not voted so how to handle that if we set vote-up value in the beginning?